# Dialogflow INVALID_ARGUMENT error on followup intent update

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

When I call the API intents.patch (https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/patch) on a followup intent using the Java SDK I receive the error:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Read-only field 'root_followup_intent_name' cannot
>   be set.

The update request I make contains only the update of the intent training phrases (I use the update mask "training_phrases"), I'm not modifying the root followup intent.

Calling the same API on a root intent has a success response. This problem has arised only in the last few days, before it worked correctly also on followup intents.

Have you got any idea of the cause?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute of the intent is a UUID defined by Dialogflow and cannot be changed (e.g. `718e3349-df8b-4d50-ac72-0de93198512a`).  To update a training phrase you need to use an existing training phrase ID from calls like [`dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.list`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dialogflow/v2/dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.list?parent=projects%252Fstagent-f2236%252Fagent&intentView=INTENT_VIEW_FULL&fields=intents%252CnextPageToken&_h=5&).  Here is an example of a valid `dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.patch` call:

```
PATCH https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/stagent-f2236/agent/intents/c757e598-c44b-485f-bcb4-01c1b0110856?intentView=INTENT_VIEW_FULL&updateMask=trainingPhrases&fields=trainingPhrases
{
 "trainingPhrases": [
  {
   "name": "718e3349-df8b-4d50-ac72-0de93198512a",
   "parts": [
    {
     "text": "updated training phrase text"
    }
   ],
   "type": "EXAMPLE"
  }
 ]
}
```

[Here is an API explorer example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dialogflow/v2/dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.patch?name=projects%252Fstagent-f2236%252Fagent%252Fintents%252Fc757e598-c44b-485f-bcb4-01c1b0110856&intentView=INTENT_VIEW_FULL&updateMask=trainingPhrases&fields=trainingPhrases&_h=3&resource=%257B%250A++%2522trainingPhrases%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522718e3349-df8b-4d50-ac72-0de93198512a%2522%252C%250A++++++%2522parts%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522text%2522%253A+%2522updated+training+phrase+text%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522EXAMPLE%2522%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&) for the same `dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.patch` call.  Note you'll need to change the value of the project ID (`stagent-f2236`) to your Dialogflow agent's project ID, the training phrase ID (`718e3349-df8b-4d50-ac72-0de93198512a`) with the ID of the training phrase you'd like to change and the text (`updated training phrase text`) to the text you'd like to update the intent training phrase to.